# How I can evaluate this integral?

Tags: integration, fourier-series

I have integral: $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{\frac{-|x|^2}{t}}\theta(t)dx$, where $\theta(t) = 0$ if $t \leq \tau$ and $\theta(t) = 1$ if $t \geq \tau$. I have no idea what I can do with Heaviside function and I tried evaluete integral without it. Nothing succeeded. I asked for help from Wolfram Alpha and Wolfram show me this answer:  $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{\frac{-|x|^2}{t}}dx$ = $\sqrt{\pi} \sqrt{t}$
erf$\big(\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{t}}\big)$, where erf - error function. And I can't understand how..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your integral is over $x$. The Heaviside function is in $t$. So you can take the Heaviside function out the front of the integral as though it were a constant.

Comment: When $t$ is fixed, you're essentially integrating $e^{x^2}$, for which there is no closed form integral ...

Comment: In my integral, $t$ is time. I have a function $f(x,t)$. 
hence my integral depends on $t$. Maybe I still need to consider an integral with a parameter?

Comment: Also, if I have an integral without the Heaviside function I can not figure out how to get an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{\frac{-|x|^2}{t}}\theta(t)dx
&=\theta(t)\int^\pi_{-\pi}e^{-x^2/t}dx \\
&=\theta(t)\int^\pi_{-\pi}e^{-(x/\sqrt t)^2}dx \\
&=\theta(t)\int^{\pi/\sqrt t}_{-\pi/\sqrt t}e^{-u^2}\sqrt t~du \qquad{(1)}\\
&=\theta(t)\sqrt t\int^{\pi/\sqrt t}_{-\pi/\sqrt t}e^{-u^2}du \\
&=\theta(t)\sqrt t\sqrt \pi\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{\pi}{\sqrt t}\right) \qquad{(2)}\\
\end{align}
$$

$(1)$: let $u=\frac{x}{\sqrt t}$.

$(2)$: due to the definition $\displaystyle{\operatorname{erf}(x):=\frac1{\sqrt\pi}\int^x_{-x}e^{-t^2}dt}$.